Python scorecardpy: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'card_df' referenced before assignment
I used scorecardpy function to get a model:
import scorecardpy as ac
card=sc.scorecard(bins_adj, lr, X_train.columns)

Then I tried to save this model using following code:
import numpy as np
np.save('card.npy',card)

After that I tried to reload this model:
card=np.load('card.npy',allow_pickle=True)

Then I want to use the model to get the scores:
score=sc.scorecard_ply(data_train, card, print_step=0)

But it gives error:
UnboundLocalError          Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [91], line 1
score=sc.scorecard_ply(data_train, card, print_step=0)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scorecardpy/scorecard.py:330, in scorecard_ply(dt, card, only_total_score, print_step, replace_blank_na, var_kp)
     card_df=card.copy(deep=True)
  # x variables
  xs=card_df.loc[card_df.variable != 'basepoints', 'variable'].unique()
  # length of x variables
  xs_len=len(xs)
  
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'card_df' referenced before assignment

How to resolve this problem?

This is (apparently) a bug inside the scorecard module.  What version are you using, and is there a newer one available that might fix the bug?

scorecardpy package version is 0.1.9.7

Using Joblib instead of Numpy will solve this problem. Remember to place import joblib at the start of your program, and replace
import numpy as np
np.save('card.npy',card)
card=np.load('card.npy',allow_pickle=True)

with
joblib.dump(card, 'card.joblib')
card = joblib.load('card.joblib')

This should not give you any errors.

Could someone explain what's wrong with this? Downvotes without any explanation kinda suck...
